# Use user-defined variables in build definition demands

Tags: tfs, build-definition

In TFS 2015 and later, is it possible to resolve a user-defined variable in the build definition demands?

---

#### Context

A build definition requires certain software `A` on its build agent, so I set the an custom [agent capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents#capabilities) `A = path/to/A`.

I want to use this path in my build definition and make sure that the build definition uses the correct path **before starting a build**.

Since TFS does not support referencing the values of agent capabilities inside steps of a *build definition* or *release definition*, I'm trying to create a workaround. I don't want to use the custom environment variable on the build machine since I want to avoid the additional build step [which is required to pass the env variable to TFS build steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#environment-variables).

The planned workaround

1. Having a variable `SoftwareA` in build definition containing `path/to/A` which can be used by the build steps.
2. In build definition -> general -> demands check if `A` equals `$(SoftwareA)`.

However `$(SoftwareA)` seems not to be resolved by TFS and instead is taken literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately the variable is never expanded outside the build/release environment.

So you need to change the demand value manually to match the path you defined in agent capabilities.

That means add demands `A` equals `path/to/A`.

There is a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/9293355-support-variable-resolution-in-demands) to suggest this feature, but it's archived. You can submit a new user voice again to suggest this feature.

Comment: I've already did it like that, so nice to know that this is the way to go atm. Thanks for the link!